# Why is this PHP code to check if yesterday was a bank holiday not working?

Tags: php, arrays, date

I am trying to check if yesterday was a UK bank holiday (using an array of known dates) and then use the boolean variable `$bankholyesterday` later on in the code to control whether or not an item from an RSS feed is displayed.

For some reason, yesterday is always being identified as a bank holiday, so my control structure is not working as intended. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
$bankhols = array ("02/01/2017", "17/04/2017", "01/05/2017", "29/05/2017", "28/08/2017", "01/01/2018", "02/04/2018", "07/05/2018", "28/05/2018", "27/08/2018", "22/04/2019", "06/05/2019", "27/05/2019", "26/08/2019", "13/04/2020", "04/05/2020", "25/05/2020", "31/08/2020");

$yesterday = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-1 days"));

$bankholyesterday = false;

foreach ($bankhols as $bankhol) {
    if (strtotime($yesterday) === strtotime($bankhol)) {
        $bankholyesterday = true;
        break;
    }
}

...

if ($bankholyesterday == true) {
    ... do the thing ...
}
```

Comment: `strtotime()` treats a `/` in the date as indicating US format (`m/d/Y`), so a date like `17/04/2017` is invalid ([PHP Docs](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php))

Comment: So why am I not encountering any errors with those dates? And why are they apparently matching yesterday's date?

Comment: @MarkBaker strtotime() returns unix time, not date format.

Comment: You almost certainly are encountering problems with them... what does `strtotime("17/04/2017")` return?... and "Yesterday" would be doing `strtotime('26/11/2017')` which is the same returned value/datatype

Comment: @MarkBaker `strtotime("-1 days")` returns `time() - (60*60*24)`

Comment: @Hallur `if (strtotime($yesterday) === strtotime($bankhol)) {`.... `if (strtotime('26/11/2017') === strtotime("17/04/2017")) {` is true because of the `/` problem.... `bool(false) === bool(false)`

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry, I didn't notice that line... see my answer below, I completely ignored it. I apologize.

Comment: @Hallur - your in_array solution is much better; I was trying to highlight the problem with OP's original attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead.

```
$bankhols = array ("02/01/2017", "17/04/2017", "01/05/2017", "29/05/2017", "28/08/2017", "01/01/2018", "02/04/2018", "07/05/2018", "28/05/2018", "27/08/2018", "22/04/2019", "06/05/2019", "27/05/2019", "26/08/2019", "13/04/2020", "04/05/2020", "25/05/2020", "31/08/2020");

$yesterday = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-1 days"));

if (in_array($yesterday, $bankhols)) {
//yesterday was bank holiday
} else {
//yesterday was not bank holiday
}
```

I tested the code and it works. I tried adding yesterdays date in the array $bankhols, and it returned true, and while it's not in the array, it returned false.

wrote a short script to convert and compare two dates, as I don't know of any alternative:

```
function compareDates($date1, $date2) {
    // date1 format = d/m/Y
    // date2 format = m/d/Y

    $d3 = explode("/", $date1);
    $date1 = $d3[1] . "/" . $d3[0] . "/" . $d3[2];

    return $date1 == $date2;
}

if (compareDates("27/11/2016", "11/27/2016")) {
    echo "dates match";
} else {
    echo "dates don't match";
}
```

Comment: As well as being much more concise, this appears to fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: If this anwers your question, then please accept the answer. otherwise, the problem you had was as MarkBaker said, this line `if (strtotime($yesterday) === strtotime($bankhol)) {` in order for it to work, you have to change the date format.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am running into a similar issue elsewhere in the code where I'm trying to check if an RSS item's date is within the past 4 or 3 or 1 days, which is presumably due to the date format issue. How would I refomat them before comparing them?